при синхронизации данных через native connector , перестает добавлять данные в индекс через 1 минуту
установлен elasticsearch enterprise, kibana.
Logstash отсутствует.
В kibana настроен коннектор, на python из официальной документации https://github.com/elastic/connectors
Коннектор используется для синхронизации данных из базы данных , в индекс elasticsearch
Настроены несколько индексов, маленькие индексы (берут данные из маленьких таблиц , до 5 тысяч записей) синхронизируются без проблем, они синхронизируются за секунд 10 .
Проблема возникает при синхронизации , индекса из большой таблицы (сотни тысяч записей)
При этом в kibana , отображается что при синхронизации документы добавляются до того момента , пока синхронизация длится меньше 1 минуты.
По прошествии 1 минуты, также пишет, что статус синхронизации
sync in progress, но новые документы больше не добавляются.
Далее по прошествии , 15 - 20 минут , вылетает ошибка connection timed out , и статус синхронизации sync failure .
Как это можно исправить?
Повторюсь , что для синхронизации не использую logstash
Ресурсов на сервере достаточно: Оперативной памяти 50 Гб , места на диске много
